# Add CorrelationId to Log instance for each time kafka client receiver message

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, microservices, serilog

I am using stack kafka and .net in my microservice architecture. i face with problem that i don't know what log messages are in sequence.

And i found the CorrelationId, i attach it to HttpHeader and easily to archive with service use http connect.

```cs
// LogEnricher
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        var headers = httpContext.Request.Headers;
        CorrelationId = headers["CorrelationId"];
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(new LogEventProperty("CorrelationId", new ScalarValue(CorrelationId)));
    }
```

```cs
// program
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) =>
            {
                configuration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
                    .ReadFrom.Services(services).Enrich.With<LogEnricher>()
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext();
                var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

                var logstashUrl = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Logging:Logstash");
                

                configuration.WriteTo.Http(logstashUrl);
            })
```

when I use kafka instead of http call.

the code i use is like this:

```cs
kafka?.Receive(async (data) =>
{
  // handle message
   executor.ExecuteEventAsync(data as IIntegrateEvent);
});
```

So how i create new logger at here and force the code using that log in this block code?

Comment: Hi, did you found a way to make it work? I'm facing the same issue here

Answer (score 0):

When using kafka. you will have a background process to receive message from kafka.

```
kafka?.Receive(async (data) =>
{
  // handle message
   executor.ExecuteEventAsync(data as IIntegrateEvent);
});
```

this is your starting point, so what you need is set `CorrelationId` to executor.

```
// mark it as scope
public class EventExecutor : IEventExecutor{
   public string CorrelationId { get; set; } = "";
}
```

and at `ExecuteEventAsync` set `CorrelationId` to `EventExecutor`. then when you want to get `CorrelationId`. just use `IServiceProvider` to get it out

```
var se = serviceProvider?.GetService<IEventExecutor>();
return se!.CorrelationId ?? "";
```

or if you just want show it on log, try it

```
using (LogContext.PushProperty("CorrelationId", dynamicMessage?.CorrelationId)){

}
```